# Can't connect to database with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to connect to my mssql database with laravel 5 but it's not working. I've tried to connect with different mssql databases so it's not a firewall issue. Also my credentials are correct. I found on google that you need SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and I've already installed that.

This is my connection array in config/database.php:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('nvt'),
            'database' => env('nvt'),
            'username' => env('nvt'),
            'password' => env('nvt'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

And I've set the default to "sqlsrv" :

```
'default' => env('sqlsrv','sqlsrv'),
```

But when I'm trying to create a table I receive the error:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 50: could not find driver

What could be wrong???

EDIT:

I've installed pdo for sqlsrv from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

And I added it to my php.ini file:
extension=\Installaties\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

But stil I receive the error?

Comment: Check if you have the PDO driver installed. `phpinfo()` will help you out with that.

Comment: Are your host, db, user and pass are the same?

Comment: No they are not the same. @Andrew when I look into phpinfo() I found this: 
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite obviously mssql is not enabled. I'm not an expert at this. So how can I enable this?

Comment: I already installed this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Comment: And I added an extension in php.ini :  extension=\Installaties\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

Comment: Are you using PHP v5.3? The `_53_` in the filename indicates that it's a version specific to php5.3. If you're running a later version of PHP, you'll need a different version of the driver as well. (btw, you *should* be running a later version of php, because 5.3 is end of life)

Comment: Is laravel running on a linux or windows machine?  What version of PHP are you using?  I assume newer than 5.4?  Is both laravel and mssql on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the eve() method, i mean use the following method

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'nvt',
        'database' => 'nvt',
        'username' => 'nvt',
        'password' => 'nvt',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Try putting in the server info directly rather than using env. If it works, then you know Laravel is having an issue reading the .env file.

Comment: Try to use the method as i mentioned above, its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered your problem the last time I tried my connection in sqlsrv. I am using xampp. Try putting yung php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll in the ext folder, replace extension=\Installaties\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll with extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll and try installing odbc 11 on your computer. It worked for me but not sure why. (not an expert) if it worked good to help a fellow person and if not, sorry for the trouble. Thank you for the time reading.

Answer (score 0):

You may try any of the following solutions

1. Check that you have entered the right connection parameters. Test by connecting to the DB with a client tool.
2. Make sure you have the right version of sqlsrv configured for your machine. Check the PHP logs to be sure your web server was able to load the extension correctly.
3. Set the port to null in your env file

As a tip, I won't advise anyone to set the connection parameters anywhere but in the .env (Setting it in config/database is a security risk).